# Can I save a PHP class method output into a variable

Tags: php

I am doing a fansite of a game where I want to show tooltips for items. I use Bootstrap tooltips to generate them. So far I've been doing tooltips for items with arrays storing the data and then display it with the BS tooltips. Now, I want to transition to OOP and i want to create classes. I am using methods inside the classes to generate the tooltip. However I have a real issue calling the method. Let me give you an example.

Current method:

```
// General variables
$rune_item_level = "<span class='white-tooltip'>Item Level: 1<br>";
$inserted_into_sockets = "Can be inserted into socketed items<br><br>";
$rune_class = "class='rune-image'";
// El Rune
$el_stats = [
    "Weapons" => "+50 To Attack Rating, +1 to Light Radius",
    "Armor" => "+15 Defense, +1 to Light Radius",
    "Helms" => "+15 Defense, +1 to Light Radius",
    "Shields" => "+15 Defense, +1 to Light Radius"
];
$el_rune_tooltip = "<span class='rune-tooltip'>El Rune</span><br>";
$el_rune_tooltip .= $rune_item_level;
$el_rune_tooltip .= $inserted_into_sockets;
foreach ($el_stats as $key=>$value){
    $el_rune_tooltip.= "<span class='white-tooltip'>" . $key . ": " . $value . "</span>";
    $el_rune_tooltip.= "<br>";
}
$el_rune_tooltip .= "<br><span class='white-tooltip'>Required Level 11";
$el_rune = '<img ' . $rune_class . ' src="/images/runes/El_Rune.png" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" title="' . $el_rune_tooltip . '" />';
```

It works well. I store the whole tooltip in into the $el_rune variable and I call whenever I want to and anywhere.

So transitioning to OOP i did the following:
I create a Rune class, pass some properties and then i use a function called createTooltip() to create the tooltip. This way my code is significantly lighter creating all 30+ runes in the game.

```
    class Rune {
    public $name, $stats, $image;
    public function __construct($name, $stats, $image){
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->stats = $stats;
        $this->image = $image;
        $this->rune_ilvl = 1;
    }
    public function createTooltip() {
            $tooltip = "<span class='rune-tooltip'>" . $this->name . "</span><br><span class='white-tooltip'>Item Level: 1<br>Can be inserted into socketed items<br><br>";
            foreach ($this->stats as $key=>$value){
                $tooltip .= "<span class='white-tooltip'>" . $key . ": " . $value . "</span>";
                $tooltip .= "<br>";
            }
            $tooltip .= "<br><span class='white-tooltip'>Required Level " . $this->rune_ilvl . "</span>";
            echo '<img class="rune-image" src="' . $this->image . '" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" title="' . $tooltip . '" />';
    }
}
$el_rune_oop = new Rune("El", $el_stats, "/images/runes/El_Rune.png");
```

So my problem is this. Before, whenever I want to call the image of the Rune item with the cool tooltip, i just do "echo $el_rune". Now if i want to do the same i need to echo $el_rune_oop->createTooltip(). It does the same job. But i have problems calling it or do cool stuff with it where with the variable, i can include it into new arrays and new structures and it's easy to remember... the $el_rune_oop->createTooltip() executes whenever i mention it anywhere, causing all sort of issues for me. I tried saving $el_rune_oop->createTooltip() itself into a variable which would be a life saver but that of course doesn't work.

Is there any salvation for me or just carry on not using OOP methods?

Comment: Have you tried using `return '<img class="rune...` when trying to store the value?

Comment: Oh my... it worked!!! Thank you. That's neat. What do you think about the whole saving the outpout into a variable. Is it ok or is there a smarter way, in your opinion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nigel Ren has given you the solution in his comment above.

Instead of "echo" in the last statement of your createTooltip method, "return" the value generated by the function.

```
    return '<img class="rune-image" src="' . $this->image . '" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" title="' . $tooltip . '" />';
```